# mb_strtolower doesn't work with french vowel é

Tags: php, function, internationalization

I have a PHP function, which delete the last letter of `$word_one` and put an apostroph to this word, when the `$word_two` begins with a vowel. But with the french vowel é it doesn't work, although  I use the `mb_strtolower` with `, 'UTF-8'`.

I don't want to change the `$pers` array, because I have also combination for words where the  `$word_two` doesn't begin with a vowel.

```
function French($word_one, $word_two) {
    if (in_array(mb_strtolower($word_two{0}, 'UTF-8'), array('a', 'e', 'é', 'i', 'o')) and ($word_one == "je" or $word_one == "que je"))    
        // delete last letter in $word_one and add an apostrophe and all of $word_two  é don't work     
        $output = substr($word_one, 0, -1) . '\'' . $word_two;        
    else
        // other wise combine the words with a space in between
        $output = $word_one . ' ' . $word_two;  
    return $output;
}
```

example:

```
$pers = array('je', "tu", "il/elle/on", "nous", "vous", "ils/elles");
$que_pers = array("que je", "que tu", "qu'il/elle/on", "que nous", "que vous", "qu'ils/elles");
$Ind['I']   = array ('étais','étais','était','étions','étiez','étaient');
$Sub['Pré'] = array ('aie','aies','ait','ayons','ayez','aient');

echo ''.French($pers[0], $Ind['I'][0]).'';
echo ''.French($que_pers[0], $Sub['Pré'][0]).'';
```

Comment: Is the source code UTF-8 too?

Comment: @dolan I think so it is for example `$Ind['I']   = array ('étais','étais','était','étions','étiez','étaient');`

Comment: Can you give me an example on the usage?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I add an example in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I got back `je étais` is that the expected result you wish to get?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No the expected result should be `j'étais`. like `j'ai` for je + ai.

Comment: I sort of expected it too. I speak French so I was going to question the fact that it should be `j'étais` - I did anticipate for that and I modified your code to be `$pers = array('j\'', "tu", "il/elle/on", "nous", "vous", "ils/elles");` or `array("j'",` try that, see if that's the result you wish to get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60340/discussion-between-grischa-and-fred-ii).

Comment: Don't use substr() to delete __characters__, substr() deletes __bytes__; use mb_substr() to delete characters.... `$word_two{0}` is also checking bytes, not characters

Comment: @MarkBaker  Thank you. Why do you post no answer? I changed 4th line to `$output = mb_substr($word_one, 0, -1) . '\'' . $word_two;`, but I don't now how to change correctly `$word_two{0}`

Comment: The problem with your code is that you saved your file as UTF-8 where is should have been ANSI, which explains why it's not working, also using `, 'UTF-8'` which should be removed - in doing so, it would have fixed your code and didn't need another piece of code as a patch.

Comment: Change `$word_two{0}` to `mb_substr($word_two, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg` functions in unicode mode (`u`) are usually easier to use than `mb_xxx`:

```
function French($word_one, $word_two) {
    if($word_one == 'je' && preg_match('~^[aeéio]~ui', $word_two))
        return "j'$word_two";
    return "$word_one $word_two";
}
```

To also match `que je` or `whatever je`:

```
if(preg_match('~(.*)\bje$~ui', $word_one, $m) && preg_match('~^[aeéio]~ui', $word_two))
    return "{$m[1]}j'$word_two";
```