# HTML between own PHP function

Tags: php, html, function

Is it possible to put HTML code in the middle of the output of a PHP function?

The `French()` function deletes the last letter of `$word_one` and appends an apostrophe to it, when `$word_two` begins with a vowel.

the function

```
function French($word_one, $word_two) {
if(preg_match('~(.*)\bje$~ui', $word_one, $m) && preg_match('~^[aeéio]~ui', $word_two)) 
    return "{$m[1]}j'$word_two";   
if(preg_match('~^[-]~ui', $word_two)) 
    return "$word_two";            
return "$word_one $word_two";      
}
```

Code using the function:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo                                        
  '<tr>'."\n".  
  '   <td><span data-text="'.French($pers[$i],  strip_tags($array[0][$i])).'" data-lang="fr" class="trigger_play">'.French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i]).'</span></td>'."\n".
  '   <td>'.French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i]).'</td>'."\n".    
  '</tr>'."\n".
```

Everything is now printed in one td.
But I want to print it in three td's, the first one is ok, but in the second and third td, it should also use the French(..) function.

How can I split `French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i])` between the two TDs and get the following?

```
'<tr>'."\n".
' <td><span data-text="'.French($pers[$i],  strip_tags($array[0][$i])).'" data-lang="fr" class="trigger_play">'.French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i]).'</span></td>'."\n".
' <td>'.$pers[$i].'</td>'.
' <td>'.$array[0][$i].'</td>'.
'</tr>'."\n".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'<tr>'."\n".
' <td>'.$pers[$i].'</td>'.
' <td>'.$array[0][$i].'</td>'.
'</tr>'."\n".
```

Don't know if this fixes your issue, since your question was pretty vague.

But man, you should really keep your quotation marks in check, not calling functions by adding them in single quotationmarks, etc. it's horrible sorry.

in the `French` function change :

`$output = $word_one . ' ' . $word_two;`

to

`$output = '<td>' . $word_one . '</td><td>' . $word_two . '</td>';`

and your php code to :

```
'<tr>'."\n"
.French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i]).
'</tr>'."\n";
```

Comment: I had corrected the second code. I want to use the function, but it should print `.French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i]).` in two tds, first `$pers[$i]` and in the second `$array[0][$i]`

Comment: What does the .French(...) function returns?

Comment: for example "j'ai" or "je suis" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594446/mb-strtolower-doesnt-work-with-french-vowel-%C3%A9)

Comment: added possible fix for you.

Comment: Thank you. I have add the function, like I use it now in the question and and an extra td, because actually I use it two times (one time for Google TTS with only a button and than printed it. I don't want to use html code every time, when I use the function.

Comment: I think it works, when I use the second idea from @lserni answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the French() function to return a different string.

Or you can add a copy of the French() function that returns a different string and call it FrenchSeparated(), so that you don't risk breaking old code that relies on current French() return format.

I'll now describe a third option: modifying the `French()` function to return not a string but an **array** (if one only did this, one would then also need to "refactor" all old code where it uses this function), but to only do this when called by the *new* code.

For portability, let's suppose that French() now only takes two arguments. You modify it to accept *three*:

```
function French($word_one, $word_two, $return_array = false) {
  // Basic, example implementation of the function - NOT the real one
    if (in_array(substr($word_two, 0, 1), array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) {
      return substr($word_one, 0, -1) . "'" . $word_two;
  }
  return $word_one . " " . $word_two;
}
```

You modify this to get an array, and return it joined:

```
function French($word_one, $word_two, $return_array = false) {
    if (in_array(substr($word_two, 0, 1), array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) {
      $coo = array( substr($word_one, 0, -1)."'", $word_two);
  } else {
      $coo = array ($word_one.' ', $word_two);
  }
  return join('', $coo);
```

Having supplied a default value ("false") for `return_array`, whenever you call the function with two parameters and omit the third, the function will receive three parameters, and the third will be set to *false*.

The function now returns the same as before. You now add a check for the new code, where `return_array` will be **true**:

```
function French($word_one, $word_two, $return_array = false) {
    if (in_array(substr($word_two, 0, 1), array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')) {
      $coo = array( substr($word_one, 0, -1)."'", $word_two);
  } else {
      $coo = array ($word_one.' ', $word_two);
  }
  if ($return_array) {
      return $coo;
  }
  return join('', $coo);
}
```

The old code now needs no modifications: the function will work as before with two parameters, and your old code only ever uses two. In the new code, when you pass a third parameter with the value of *true*, the function will return both word separately.

So you can do:

```
 list($one, $two) = French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i], true);

 echo "<tr><td>{$one}</td><td>{$two}</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If "French" is your own function, try this:

```
function French($a, $b, $glue='') {
   //do your logical stuff
   return $result_a . $glue . $result_b;

}
```

and wherever you call, do this:

```
echo '<tr>\n<td>' . French($pers[$i], $array[0][$i], '</td><td>') .'</td>\n</tr>';
```